# the result of linking two strong function symbol with the same function signature use g++ and why?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, symbols

I am confused about the linking procedure when linking two same function symbol.

point.h:

```
#ifndef _POINT_H_
#define _POINT_H_

struct dpoint_t
{
    /* data */
    double x, y;
};

struct ipoint_t
{
    /* data */
    int x, y;
};

#ifdef DOUBLE_POINT
    typedef struct dpoint_t data;
#else
    typedef struct ipoint_t data;
#endif

struct Point
{
    data p;
    int idx;
};
/*
#ifndef DOUBLE_POINT
__attribute__ ((weak)) 
#endif
*/
void * get_y(struct Point &x);

#endif
```

point.cpp:

```
#include "point.h"


void * get_y(struct Point &pt)
{
    int a = 1;
    return &(pt.p.y);
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"

int main()
{
    struct Point x;
    x.p.x = 10.0;
    x.p.y = 5.0;
    void *p = get_y(x);
    printf("double: %lf\nint: %d\n", *(double *)p, *(int *)p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get two objects by

```
g++ -o double_point -DDOUBLE_POINT -c point.cpp
g++ -o int_point -c point.cpp
```

and let use g++ to link them together with test.cpp

My question is:

**why I can link them successfully, I mean there are 2 same symbol, why ld doesn't get error**

**I think if I use weak symbol on one of the functions, the linking result will always be the strong function symbol, but the result doesn't change, it always be the symbol that come first, I want to know why**

my compiler:

GNU C++ version 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2).

GNU assembler version 2.15.92.0.2 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version 2.15.92.0.2 20040927

Comment: Do you mean parameter `pt` and `x` are different in function `get_y`??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the following links :

[C++: Different classes with the same name in different translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364720/c-different-classes-with-the-same-name-in-different-translation-units)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the One Definition Rule, and thus causing undefined behavior. While I understand what you might be wanting to do, the fact is that your code is wrong and the compiler toolchain does not need to provide any specific behavior.

What is the real problem you want to solve? Because this is clearly not the way to the solution.

Comment: Rodriguez: I'm not try to solve problem, but just want to figure out these concepts. I read the ODR, still have questions: **if in one object the symbol is weak symbol, why the result of the linking isn't always the strong symbol**

Comment: @zuanyg: That is unrelated to the language, but the particular linker you are using. From the point of view of the language, your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required and *anything* can happen. I am not that familiar with usages of the linker outside of what the standard sanctions, so I cannot further comment. Read your linker's documentation.