# conflicting C++ classes in different modules get mixed up without link error

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, vtable

While working on embedded code (ESP32 with IDF 4.4.3, gcc 8.4) I encountered strange crashes that did not make sense at all. After spending half a day (without debugger) I discovered, that I had two classes with the same name in two modules.
(accidentally renamed both after copy of the module A to new B.)

The code looked like this.

some include file:

```
class pull_data_source
{
public:
   virtual ~pull_data_source() {}
   virtual int get(char* data, int max_length) = 0;
};
```

module A.cpp:

```
class dummy_source : public http::pull_data_source
{
public:
   dummy_source(const dummy_source&) = delete;
   dummy_source& operator=(const dummy_source&) = delete;

...some static function

   int get(char* data, int max_length) override
   {
...some code
   }

private:
   http::server* server;
   uint64_t size;

   dummy_source(http::server* server, uint64_t size) : server(server), size(size)
   {}
};
```

module B.cpp:

```
//same as in A.cpp for the shown parts but different implementation (omitted ... parts)
```

I expect to get a linker error for such code. Instead the classes got some what mixed up. (My guess is that the class in B used the vtable of the class in A)

Can someone explain, what was happening.
Is there a linker option or something else to ensure, such code does produce an error?

PS: Code in B was working, when defining get() out of class instead of inline. I have not tested A in this case. Maybe I would have had a link error when doing this to A too.

Comment: See dupe: [C++: Different classes with the same name in different translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364720/c-different-classes-with-the-same-name-in-different-translation-units)

Comment: Violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR); undefined behavior, no diagnostic required.

Comment: If you compile with `-flto`, you should get warnings.